# SQLAlchemy insert into table passing table name as a string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-insert

I have a dictionary with 20 items. Keys are actually table names, and  values are single values that needs to go into 20 separate tables.
How can I do it using SQLAlchemy without writing 20 if statements?

Example:

```
class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table1"
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String())

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table2"
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String())

class Table3(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table3"
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String())
...
class Table20(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table20"
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String())

mydict = {
    'table1': 'some value'
    'table2': 'some value'
    'table3': 'some value'
    ...
    'table20': 'some value'
}
```

Now I'm using 20 if statements:

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
    if key == 'table1':
        session.add(Table1(value=value))
    if key == 'table2':
        session.add(Table2(value=value))
    if key == 'table3':
        session.add(Table3(value=value))
    ...
    if key == 'table20':
        session.add(Table20(value=value))
```

Comment: Are the tables really that simple and similar, or is this a "minimal" example? :) Because if they are, you should rethink your schema. Namely instead of 20 separate tables have 1 table like `(key, value)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look the table up in `Base.metadata.tables` and then insert:

```
for tbl, value in mydict.items():
    stmt = Base.metadata.tables[tbl].insert().values(value=value)
    session.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: Thank you Ilja, I will give it a try. Is there any way to make a bulk insert  for 20 items?

Comment: No, not with 20 separate tables.

Comment: Alright Ilja. Your method is working. The only problem is - I have date column in every table with default=datetime.now. And default value is not triggered when I'm inserting using this method.

Comment: Either use server defaults, or something along the lines of `values(value=value, the_date_col=datetime.utcnow())`. Though: it should actually use the default, even if using the Core insert statement, so something's amiss.